# What is different between App.Current.Properties["some"] and Application.Current.Properties["some"]

Tags: c#, wpf

What is different between these two classes (App and Application). I make WPF application, and do I need to be careful where I use App and where I use Application class. Now I use `App.Current.Properties["property"] = property;`, but before I used `Application.Current.Properties["property"] = property;`. And the both cases is working. Are there have any differences.

Answer (score 4):

It's the same. `App` is declared like this

```
class App : Application
```

so it *inherits* (if I can say so) all static properties (including `Current` one).